# Example for conditional Distribution and correlation between variables following normal distribution

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

A car company tests an upcoming car model for gas consumption $(x_1)$ and oil consumption $(x_2)$.From past tests it is known that the expected gas consumption is  and the expected oil consumption is 1 Liter per 130kms(I believe these mean the Avg value).It is also known that the consumpion follows normal distribution and also the matrix of covariance is

$$
=\begin{pmatrix} 0.10 & 0.05 \\ 0.05 & 0.10 \end{pmatrix}
$$

A new variable $ = \frac{1}{2}  _ + \frac{1}{2}_$   represents the total consumption.

According to measurements, the gasoline consumption is 1.5 liters in 10,000 kilometers, and the engine oil consumption is 2 liters in 1,000 kilometers based on the measurements obtained from the tests.

$1)$What is the distribution of the total consumption?

$2)$What is the correlation between the two consumptions?

$3)$Assuming zero correlation between the two consumptions, calculate how the distribution of the total consumption changes.

I would like someone to guide me through an exercise like this so I can undestand the logic behind these problems and also correct me if I made any mistakes since i have answered questions 2 and 3.

Ps$(1)$: Since both $x_1$ and $x_2$ follow normal distribution we have that for $x_1$ $  N(\frac{8}
{50},0.1)$ and for $x_2$ $  N(\frac{1}{130},0.1)$ In my experience that would mean that $y$ would also follow normal distribution but im not quite sure since we dont know if $x_1 , x_2$ are dependent or not.

Ps$(2)$: I believe that in the question number $2$ we are talking about Pearson correlation coefficient. So if thats the case i believe we have $r(x_1,x_2)= \frac{Cov(x_1,x_2)}{σ(x_1)*σ(x_2)}=\frac{0.05}{\sqrt(0.10)*\sqrt(0.10)}=\frac{0.05}{0.10}=\frac{1}{2}=0.5$

Ps$(3)$: Since we have independent $x_1 , x_2$ then $μ=\frac{1}{2}*(\frac{8}{50}+\frac{1}{130})=\frac{109}{1300}$ and $σ^2=\frac{1}{4}*(0.1+0.1)=0.05$. So y follows $N(\frac{109}{1300},0.05)$

Comment: *"...any mistakes since i have $X_1, X_2$ are dependent or not.*" If $X_1,$ and $X_2$ are normal distributed then $a\cdot X_1+b \cdot X_2$ ( linear combination) is normal distributed as well. In total it seems all fine.

Comment: Very strange to have (engine) oil consumption as high as gas(oline) consumption, and also strange to say total consumption is the average rather than the total. Meanwhile "1 Liter per 130kms" is not even the same scale as "1.5 liters in 10,000 kilometers"